# Carry out computation for coordinates in each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a pandas dataframe(df) with co-ordinates (latitude(Lat), longitude(Lon)) and name of the place.
I want to extract particular entries which satisfy the below condition

```
 acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) <= 0.1570;
```

How can I compute this with df.loc ?

Attaching my df.head() screenshot
[image: df.head()]

Comment: Are Lat and Lon in separate columns? Would be helpful if you posted the dataframe in your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: @RyoheiNamiki I edited my question to include a few entries of the dataframe. Thanks

Comment: I think you should be more explicit.
assign the outcome to a variable and then you can easily use loc to match rows by matching to the said variable, using loc is fast and this way you're more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
df[np.arccos(np.sin(1.3963) * np.sin(df["lat"]) + np.cos(1.3963) * np.cos(df["lat"]) * np.cos(df["long"] - (-0.6981))) <= 0.1570]
```